# Properties of Cesàro Operator in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

Put $L^2=L^2(0,\infty)$ relative to Lebesgue measure, and the Cèsaro operator $C$
is defined as follows:
$$(Cf)(s)=\frac{1}{s}\int_0^s f(t)dt$$
we can find its adjoint operator:
\begin{align*}
\langle Cf,g\rangle=&\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{s}\int_0^s f(t)dt\right)\overline{g(s)}ds\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\left(\int_t^{\infty} \frac{1}{s}f(t)\overline{g(s)}ds\right)dt\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}f(t)\left(\int_t^{\infty} \frac{1}{s}\overline{g(s)}ds\right)dt\\
\end{align*}
Hence the adjoint is given by
$$(C^*f)(t)=\int_t^{\infty} \frac{1}{s}f(s)ds$$
How can I justify the change of the integration limits in the inner integral in the second equality?

I leave the link from where I obtained the proof: https://desvl.xyz/2021/07/08/Cesaro-operator-in-L2/

Comment: You can rewrite $$ \int_0^\infty \int_0^s \dots dt ds = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty 1_{(0,s)}(t) \dots dt ds =\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty 1_{(0,s)}(t) \dots ds dt = \int_0^\infty \int_t^\infty 1_{(0,s)}(t) \dots ds dt = \int_0^\infty \int_t^\infty \dots ds dt. $$ Here we used that $1_{(0,s)}(t)=0$ for $s\leq t$ and $1_{(0,s)}(t)=1$ for $s>t$.

Comment: The part that really needs justification is the second equality in my previous comment. There you want to use something like Fubini's theorem. I have not check whether Fubini applies in this situation.

Comment: Why in the last two equalities, is $0$ replaced with $t$, and then in the next equality, the function $1_{(0,s)}(t)$ is removed?

Comment: I used the definition of $1_{(0,s)}(t)$ as explained in my first comment. I can remove the part where $s<t$ as $1_{(0,s)}(t)=0$ in this region. Furthermore, in the remaining region the function equals $1$, so we can remove it all together.

Comment: I don't understand why changing the integration limits preserves the equality  $\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty} 1_{(0,s)}(t)...dsdt=\int_0^{\infty}\int_t^{\infty}1_{(0,s)}(t)...dsdt$?

Comment: I explained it in my last comment. If you integrate over $0$, then you can drop that term.

Comment: I have expanded my comments as an answer. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Yes, It is clear. Thanks!

Comment: In that case you should accept the answer to get this question off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We write
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{s} \left( \int_0^s f(t) dt \right) \overline{g(s)} ds
= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{s} 1_{(0,s)}(t) f(t) \overline{g(s)} dt ds.
\end{align*}
Now we would like to change the order of integration. In order to do so, we use the Fubini-Tonelli theorem. In order to do so, we need to show that the iterated integral with absolute values is finite. Using Cauchy-Schwarz and Hardy's inequality we get
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{s} \int_0^s \vert f(t) \vert dt \right) \vert g(s) \vert ds
&\leq \left(\int_0^\infty \left\vert \frac{1}{s} \int_0^s \vert f(t) \vert dt \right\vert^2 ds \right)^{1/2} \left( \int_0^\infty \vert g(s) \vert^2 ds \right)^{1/2} \\
&\leq 2 \Vert f \Vert_2 \Vert g \Vert_2<\infty.
\end{align*}
After changing the order of integration we get
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{s} \left(\int_0^s f(t)dt\right) \overline{g(s)} ds
= \int_0^\infty f(t) \left(\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{s} 1_{(0,s)}(t) \overline{g(s)} ds \right).
\end{align*}
We are left to get rid of the indicator function and adjust the lower limit of integration. For this we note that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{s} 1_{(0,s)}(t) \overline{g(s)} ds
&= \int_0^t \frac{1}{s} \underbrace{1_{(0,s)}(t)}_{=0} \overline{g(s)} ds + \int_t^\infty \frac{1}{s} \underbrace{1_{(0,s)}(t)}_{=1} \overline{g(s)} ds \\
&= \int_t^\infty \frac{1}{s} \overline{g(s)} ds.
\end{align*}